# Unable to update personal statement on careers

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, cv

I'm trying to update my personal profile. Changed fields usually display the *draft* marker when you move to the next field, but this just doesn't happen with personal statement.

I can hit <kbd>Save</kbd>, but nothing changes...

No error...
No change...
[No soup for you today](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Soup_Nazi)...

Comment: Yup, I can confirm. Will fix asap.

Comment: I rolled back your *status-completed* tag, since it's still not working even though you said it's been resolved.

Comment: You can roll back an administrator tag? Good to know. (Off to remove some `status-completed` s)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now that they called in the big guns, it's really fixed :)

Answer (score 2):

All better now... Apologies for any inconvenience. As it turns out, some code on that page is dependent on an older version of jQuery. Updating it broke things, so we put the old version back.

Comment: **I don't see any difference**. And the thing was that none of the *Personal Information* fields worked when you changed/filled them. And I still see the same thing. It doesn't save the information I enter. In any of them.

Comment: @Robert Did you do a hard refresh?

Comment: As in `Ctrl-F5`... Yes. Several times. Focusing on *website* field should clear it and make change text color to normal (darker). But it doesn't. Anyway. It doesn't do anything on fields in the *Personal Info* section.

Comment: ok - we can repro. Even though it works for us (we tested this on our own CVs prior to saying it was fixed), it is still broken in some cases. Hang tight.